# Border Radius Animation

Tags: jquery, css

I am building a site on Squarespace and I am trying to get the border radius of the first page to change while scrolling. The animation works perfectly in the Squarespace preview but if I go on another computer or in incognito mode on Chrome it doesn't work. The border radius isn't even changed it just remains flat. Is there something conflicting in my code?

CSS:

```
#intro{
  border-top-left-radius: 0% !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 0% !important;
  width: 150vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  right: 26vw;
  height: 800px;
}
```

JQuery:

```
<script>
var hHeight = $("html").height(),
    radius  = 100;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
      percent   = 150 - ((150*scrollTop)/hHeight) * 2;
  $("#intro").css("border-radius", percent + "%");
});
</script>
```

Comment: seems to work for me, though I'm not sure exactly what effect you're trying to achieve [codepen](https://codepen.io/sathomas/pen/EvLKZg)

Comment: This is a visual of what I am trying to do  [codepen](https://codepen.io/yy/pen/ByrMZR)

Answer (score 8):

Why don't just use transition style?

```css
#main {
  background: white;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: border-radius ease 0.5s;
}
#main:hover {
  border-radius: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"> </div>
```

And if you want to bind it to scroll(e.g. mousewheel) event:

!!Updated: added scroll locking, and modified the border-radius modifying throug events.

```js
function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}
function disableScroll() {
  window.onwheel = preventDefault;
}
function enableScroll() {
  window.onwheel = null;
}
var elem = document.getElementById('main');
elem.onmouseover = disableScroll;
elem.onmouseout = enableScroll;
console.log(elem);
elem.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) {
 var delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;
  var base = elem.style.borderRadius;
  if (base) {
   base = parseInt(base.match(/(\d+)px/)[1]);
  } else base = 0;
  var NEW = base;
  if (delta > 0) 
    NEW = base +2;
  else 
    NEW = base -2;
  elem.style.borderRadius = NEW+"px";
});
```

```css
body{
    height:200px;
}

#main {
  background: white;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: border-radius ease 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: Because it isn't a hover effect. It happens as the user scrolls down the page. The radius starts at 100% and as the scroll it goes down to 0.

Comment: @RyanDeshaies Updated answer, see it now on `scrolls down/up`.